# Selecting elements for clipping in web pages with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, selection

Currently I'm trying to make a web clipping chrome extension.

I have considered 2 options

1. Render the html of selected elements to a canvas element using [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) and then optionally save it as an image file using [canvas2image](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/).
2. The second option is to get the inner html of the selected elements and their styling and somehow reproduce the element on the clipboard.

For both the methods I need to first let the user select the elements graphically by dragging around a selecting box or something.But I can not really figure out how to do that.
What are the possible solutions?

On a side note, I'll really appreciate some input on the feasibility of the above 2  methods .

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you looking for getting a snapshot of the selection as an image

Comment: or you want just the user selected text

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara i want to select every type of element including images and videos ..for text only i know the possible solution can be `window.getSelection();`

Comment: I know the way to get images , but I am not sure whether you will be successful in getting videos , because there may be a video embedded with in the html5 player in that case you can get the src but in case of flash you can get the flv source or you can get the swf source so perfectly . At any time getting videos is always not 100 % stable

Comment: If you are intrested in getting only images from the selection Please update your post I will post it

Comment: I am interested in any possible solution :). Please go ahead and post whatever solution you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var selection = document.getSelection();
var range = selection.getRangeAt(selection.rangeCount - 1).cloneRange();
var clonedSelection = range.cloneContents();
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(clonedSelection);
var html = div.innerHTML;
return html;
```

This gets the job done :). Tested on normal text , images and youtube videos too :).

Answer (score 1):

As per our conversation in the comments . I am posting the solution for the getting images from the User selection

Here is the steps to get the images after parsing the users selected content

As you have already mentioned use this to get the selected HTML

```
 $sel = document.commandDispatcher.focusedWindow.getSelection();
```

Now you have the complete innerHTML of the users selection along with the tags and attributes 
you have to serialize to string to process it

```
var node = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneContents();       
var htmlContent = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(node);
```

Later get use javascript DOM parser to parse the htmlcontent

loop through the each element and get image tags

like this

```
 var parser = new DOMParser();
 var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(htmlContent, "text/xml");
```

foreach image tag you parse

```
 var image_src = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute("src");
```

Now variable image_src holds the the actual complete src path of the image user selected 
​

Comment: Thanks for your effort. +1. But got a all round solution after some research.See my answer :)